# What is the best way to package/host a Vue.js component in an existing application

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, reactjs, vue.js

We have several applications in the wild that use a variety of front-end frameworks (Angular 1.5, Aurelia, Durandal, ReactJS, MVC, etc...)  We're looking to move forward with a single framework, one of the requirements is that it can be 'easily' incorporated into our existing applications.

With Vue it seems simple enough to build a reusable component however, it isn't clear how best to incorporate it into an existing application.  I was hoping there would be a way to package up a .vue file and simply 'reference' it in an existing app.

I'm sure this problem been solved several times before.  Anyone have any best practices for accomplishing this?

Comment: Are you using `.vue` files?

Comment: Ideally I'd like to package a component in a single .vue file